# I can't vote (nothing happens when I click my choices)

Tags: bug, election

I just tried to vote, and after I click my first (or second) choice, nothing happens (I have always voted, so I know that the choices are supposed to be highlighted).

I'm using Safari 9.1.1 at a Mac using OS X 10.9.5

EDIT: It is definitely a bug if using Safari. I tried with Google Chrome 66 Mac and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: **No class is added**

Could you open dev tools on the election page and look at the classlist of the button you clicked? It should say `selected-choice` if you clicked it. I would assume, although this is uncertain, that your vote has come through if you're seeing this class and it is just a rendering issue.

[image: selected-choice class]

Step 2:

Open up dev tools again, and select the button and click 'Event listeners'. is there an event listener attached to the button? If so, click through to the JS file by clicking the underlined link after the event listener name (in this case 4:718)

[image: event listener]

Comment: It doesn't add the class; also I know this wasn't going to, because when you vote, your choices are gathered at the right column.

Comment: Hmpf, strange, I can't find anything on this in the [SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=election+page+safari) either. Could you maybe join us in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot) to help clarify the issue?

Comment: I tried with Chrome and it worked, it is definitely a bug with Safari. I won't do any further testing. BTW, thank you for your help and dedication!

Comment: No prob. I'm leaving this open for now, as some dev from SE might actually pass along triggered by the [tag:bug] tag

Comment: I tried it on Safari and didn't have an issue. [tag:status-norepro]